# Sort product by category

Tags: magento-1.9, sorting, category-products

I use this code for get products :

```
public function getProducts()
{
    $product = Mage::getModel("catalog/product")
                    ->getCollection()
                    ->addAttributeToSelect('*')
                    ->addAttributeToFilter('star', ['gt' => 0])
                    ->addFieldToFilter('visibility', Mage_Catalog_Model_Product_Visibility::VISIBILITY_BOTH)
                    ->addAttributeToFilter(
                        'status',
                        ['eq' => Mage_Catalog_Model_Product_Status::STATUS_ENABLED]
                    )
                    ->setPageSize(self::NB_PRODUCTS)
    ;
    return $product;
}
```

I want to add a filter, for get only category id #3 products per exemple.
I try to add :

```
// ...
->addAttributeToFilter('category_id', array('in' => array('finset' => 3)))
//...
```

But it dont works :

```
Fatal error: Call to a member function getBackend() on boolean in mylocalserver\app\code\core\Mage\Eav\Model\Entity\Abstract.php on line 816
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try below code for category product collection

```
    $categoryId = 3;
   $product = Mage::getModel("catalog/category")->load($categoryId)
                ->getProductCollection()
                ->addAttributeToSelect('*')
                ->addAttributeToFilter('star', ['gt' => 0])
                ->addFieldToFilter('visibility', Mage_Catalog_Model_Product_Visibility::VISIBILITY_BOTH)
                ->addAttributeToFilter(
                    'status',
                    ['eq' => Mage_Catalog_Model_Product_Status::STATUS_ENABLED]
                )
                ->setPageSize(self::NB_PRODUITS)
;
return $product;
```

Comment: You are always Welcome :)

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
$products = Mage::getModel('catalog/category')->load($category_id)
 ->getProductCollection()
 ->addAttributeToSelect('*') // add all attributes - optional
 ->addAttributeToFilter('status', 1) // enabled
 ->addAttributeToFilter('visibility', 4) //visibility in catalog,search
 ->setOrder('price', 'ASC'); //sets the order by price
```